# What's the proper way to UNION a list of queries in SQLAlchemy (Python)?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

So I have a list of SQLAlchemy `Query` objects and I want to UNION all of them.

For example if I have in my list the equivalent of:

```
SELECT id, name FROM person
SELECT id, name FROM employee
```

I would get the equivalent of:

```
(SELECT id, name FROM person)
UNION
(SELECT id, name FROM employee)
```

I don't know what's in the list and the list could contain many `Query` objects but of course the result signature of each SQLAlchemy `Query` object in my list is 100% identical.

At the moment I do the UNION like this:

```
if not q_list:
    return []

big_q = q_list.pop(0)
if q_list:
    big_q = big_q.union(*q_list)
result = [dict(row) for row in dbsession.execute(big_q)]
```

But for some weird reason I don't get the same result as if I were running all the queries individually then concatenating the results together. I must do the union incorrectly. How do I do the UNION then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem had nothing to do with the `union` call. My queries list to UNION was created with a function which was doing something like this on each object:

```
sql.expression.bindparam(
    "current_timestamp", value=start_timestamp
)
```

It seems that since all my query object in my list had the same params names (`current_timestamp`) they all used the same value instead of their individual value when `bindparam` was used.

I just had to use the `unique` parameter to fix my problem:

```
sql.expression.bindparam(
    "current_timestamp", unique=True, value=start_timestamp
)
```

That way they all get their `start_timestamp` value as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be expecting `UNION ALL`.

From the [postgresql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/queries-union.html), the second part..

> UNION effectively appends the result of query2 to the result of query1
> (although there is no guarantee that this is the order in which the
> rows are actually returned).

> Furthermore, it eliminates duplicate rows
> from its result, in the same way as DISTINCT, unless UNION ALL is
> used.

Try this:

```py
if q_list:
    big_q = big_q.union_all(*q_list)
```

There is also a function to perform [union all](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.union_all), like:

```py
q = union_all(*q_list)
```